# Sometimes the VLQ flag is not an option. Why?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

This in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919736/1253312

[image]

Why is "Low Quality" not an option here, but it does appear on other questions?

Comment: Hm, nevermind, I found the dupe. VTC please. I'd prefer to keep this question here and closed rather than deleted, because the SEO on the other question sucks.

Comment: you should have sufficient rep to VTC yourself as well.

Comment: I did vtc. Somehow the question was not auto-closed though. Strange.

Comment: It won't autoclose, it still needs 5 votes.  I just realized that you were the possible duplicate link.  When I read it first, I thought it was someone else.